# How to connect mongodb(installed on ec2) to Robomongo?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, robo3t

I have mongodb installed on `aws ec2` up and running. Now i want to connect that `mongodb` to my `Robo3T` client. So in `connection` tab i put my public `ipv4` `ip` in `address` field, put `27017` in `port(connection tab)`.

Then in `SSH` tab of `Robo3t` i again put my public `ipv4` `ip` in `SSH address` field and put `22` in port field. in `SSH User Name` field i put default `ubuntu`and select `private key` method from dropdown `SSH Auth Method` field. Then i browse my `.pem` file. But it is not connecting and giving me this error

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

I also have done `port` configuration on `aws`. Please see below :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set **Address**: `localhost`

[image]